# How do you see more than the Last Opened date when an application was launched on Mac?

Tags: applications, metadata

I'd like to find more dates that I've opened an application besides the latest date shown under the Last Opened field.

I was going through my list of apps and found some old ones which I had forgotten about. Trying to jog my memory surrounding them, I stupidly launched them instantly before checking the Get info module for more info on when they were last opened. Now all I see is the current date displayed, and would really like to see earlier launch dates if possible.

Is there any way to see more? A history must be available somewhere right?

Answer (score 1):

See the `kMDItemUsedDates` field of the output of command

```
mdls "/Applications/Sublime Text.app"
```

or any other app.

```
mdls "/Applications/Sublime Text.app" -name kMDItemUsedDates
```

will also work.